# IX509Extension XCN encoding?

Tags: powershell, certenroll

I understand from reading [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378077(v=vs.85).aspx) 
that the X509 v3 extensions must be handcrafted. This involves the CRL, AIA, name and policy constraints, policy mapping, private key usage period, and subject directory attributes.

I tried to make a CRL distribution point but the result is garbage:

```
    $crlExt = New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509Extension
    $crlOid = New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CObjectId
    $crlOid.InitializeFromValue('2.5.29.31')
    $crlValue = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('http://www.test.com'))
    $crlExt.Initialize($crlOid, 0x1, $crlValue)
    $crlExt.Critical = $false
```

Is there any reference on how to encode the values for each of the following? I have searched all over but no luck.

- AuthorityInformationAccess
- CrlDistributionPoints
- FreshestCRL
- NameConstraints
- PolicyConstraints
- PolicyMappings
- PrivateKeyUsagePeriod
- SubjectDirectoryAttributes

Note that this is about the certenroll com interface in Windows. openssl is not applicable here.

Comment: Most of them are defined (in ASN.1 format) in RFC5280, ASN.1 module appendixes.

Comment: But is there not way but to roll your own? CryptoEncodeObjectEx seems hopeful but still can't figure it out.

Comment: I have implemented few managed extension classes in PSPKI module: http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/N_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates.htm, new extensions are expected to appear in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came across the same issue in C#, trying to generate certificates with CDPs (CRL Distribution Points) extension through CertEnroll.dll

The only way I could make this work was by handcrafting the extension at byte level, though I didn't find any documentation about how the bytes should be ordered or the meaning of some bytes. To figure it out I generated some certs using OpenSSL in Linux and inspected the raw bytes in C# (load the certificate in [X509Certificate2 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) and take a look at the `Extensions` property. The [X509Extension class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509extension(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `RawData` property).

You should be able to convert my code to PowerShell, so I ended up with:

```
var urisStr = new string[]
{
    "http://pki.example.com/list.crl"
};
var uris = urisStr.Select(u => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(u));
var zero = new byte[] { 48 }; //"0", delimiter ?
var nbsp = new byte[] { 160 }; //"&nbsp;", separator ?
var dagger = new byte[] { 134 }; //"dagger", separator ?

var zeroSize = zero.Length + 1;
var nbspSize = nbsp.Length + 1;
var daggerSize = dagger.Length + 1;

var col = new List<byte>();
col.AddRange(zero); //delimiter
int totalBytes = uris.Sum(u => u.Length);
totalBytes += (zeroSize + (nbspSize * 2) + daggerSize) * uris.Count();
col.Add((byte)totalBytes); //size of everything it contains

foreach (var uri in uris)
{
    var uriSize = uri.Length;
    col.AddRange(zero); //delimiter
    col.Add((byte)(nbspSize + nbspSize + uriSize + daggerSize)); //size of everything it contains
    col.AddRange(nbsp);
    col.Add((byte)(nbspSize + uriSize + daggerSize)); //size of everything it contains
    col.AddRange(nbsp);
    col.Add((byte)(uriSize + daggerSize)); //size of everything it contains
    col.AddRange(dagger); //separator ?
    col.Add((byte)uriSize);
    col.AddRange(uri);
}
var bytes = col.ToArray();
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var oidCDP = new CObjectId();
oidCDP.InitializeFromName(CERTENROLL_OBJECTID.XCN_OID_CRL_DIST_POINTS);

// There is no specific class to CDPs, so we use the CX509Extension
var crlList = new CX509Extension();
crlList.Initialize(oidCDP, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, base64);
certRequest.X509Extensions.Add(crlList);
```

Please note that **I didn't found any documentation about the format of the bytes that I'm generating, so this code has no official basis**. It's based only on observations of working certificates.